# Is it possible to write special characters using the alt key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to be able to type characters such as ellipse and em dash using the same key combinations as in osx (that is, alt+period for ellipse, alt+dash for endash, alt+shift+dash for emdash, etc.
I checked my keyboard layout file which indicates that such characters should writable :

```
key <AB09>  { [    period,      colon, ellipsis,   periodcentered ] };
key <AB10>  { [     minus, underscore,       endash,       emdash ] };
```

However when I try to write the these characters using the alt key I'm only able to produce  . :   and  - _

I know I can produce these characters by defining and using compose key, but if it's possible I'd much prefer my keyboard to behave as it does in osx

Comment: If your keyboard layout includes those lines, you should be able to do what you want by using <Right Alt> instead of <Left Alt>. Can you as a first step confirm that that is the case?

Comment: Neither Left Alt nor Right Alt worked when trying to make those characters. I tried going into org.gnome.desktop.input-sources and adding 'lv3:ralt_switch', 'misc:typo'. It looks like the 3th and 4th level characters are now enabled, although not mapped correctly. When I type alt+period I get », alt+shift+period gives >, alt+dash gives … and so on

Comment: That's odd. Which keyboard layout are you using? Is it possibly the Norwegian layout?

Comment: Yes. It's a Norwegian macbook pro layout that I got from here: https://github.com/gulrotkake/Ubuntu-MacBook-Norwegian-keyboard

Comment: Well, I simply added the original Norwegian layout, and it let me use <Right Alt> as I said without any further actions. You may have screwed up the setup of that MacBook variant somehow. Can you please edit your question and let us know the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Second thoughts: I think you should ask a new question, where you refer to that github project, explain in detail which steps you took to apply it on your machine, and describe exactly how the result does not meet your expectations. Why? Because all important info here tends to be in comments instead of the question, and that's not how Ask Ubuntu is supposed to work.